# Create dictionary and see if key always has same value

Tags: python, dictionary

If I had a file of lines starting with a number followed by some text, how could I see if the numbers are always followed by different text? For example:

```
0 Brucella abortus Brucellaceae
0 Brucella ceti Brucellaceae
0 Brucella canis Brucellaceae
0 Brucella ceti Brucellaceae
```

So here, I'd like to know that `0` is followed by 3 different "types" of text.

Ideally I could read a file into a python script that would have output something like this:

```
1:250
2:98
3:78
4:65
etc.
```

The first number would be the number of different "texts", and the number after the `:` would be how many numbers have this occurring.

I have the following script that calculates how many times a "text" is found in different numbers, so I'm wondering how to kind of reverse it so I know how many times a `number` has different texts, and how many different texts are present. This script makes the files of `numbers` and "text" into a dictionary but I'm unsure of how to manipulate this dictionary to get what I want.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 #Dictionary to broken species, genus, family

 fileIn = 'usearchclusternumgenus.txt'

 d = {}
 with open(fileIn, "r") as f:
         for line in f:
                 clu, gen, spec, fam = line.split()
                 d.setdefault(clu, []).append((spec))


 # Iterate through and find out how many times each key occurs
 vals = {}                       # A dictonary to store how often each value occurs.
 for i in d.values():
   for j in set(i):              # Convert to a set to remove duplicates
     vals[j] = 1 + vals.get(j,0) # If we've seen this value iterate the count
                                 # Otherwise we get the default of 0 and iterate it
 #print vals

 # Iterate through each possible freqency and find how many values have that count.
 counts = {}                     # A dictonary to store the final frequencies.
 # We will iterate from 0 (which is a valid count) to the maximum count
 for i in range(0,max(vals.values())+1):
     # Find all values that have the current frequency, count them
     #and add them to the frequency dictionary
     counts[i] = len([x for x in vals.values() if x == i])

for key in sorted(counts.keys()):
   if counts[key] > 0:
      print key,":",counts[key]`
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you are calculating here. My answer simplified your code; calculating per `clu` how many unique `spec` values there are.

Comment: That's a good way to say what I'm looking for actually. I'm looking for how many times (or how many `clu`) have unique `spec`. Eventually I'd like to see which ones, but first I want to know how many times it happens.

Comment: Your terms *text* and *number* are very confusing though. Can you give me a small sample of input lines and expected output for those lines?

Comment: How do unique `spec` values correlate to the numbers you show in your sample output? `ceti` is listed twice with `clu` `0` for example, `abortus` once and `canus` once.. My answer right now will  output `0:3` as there are 3 unique `spec` values for `clu` `0`, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguousness of my terms! It would be a number, `0` and then the value is the text is the whole line `Brucella abortus Brucellaceae.`

Comment: @MartijnPieters so yes you're right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a set as the factory to track different lines, then print out the sizes of the collected sets:

```
from collections import defaultdict

unique_clu = defaultdict(set)

with open(fileIn) as infh:
    for line in infh:
        clu, gen, spec, rest = line.split(None, 3)
        unique_clu[clu].add(spec)

for key in sorted(unique_clu):
    count = len(unique_clu[key])
    if count:
        print '{}:{}'.format(key, count)
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran this and I got an error at this line: `unique_clu[clu].add(spec)` (says unique_clu is undefined), should `unique_clu[clu]` be `unique_spec`?

Comment: This is great! Is there a quick way to see how many times a `clu` has a value of 1? So how many time `clu:1`? Thank very much!

Comment: Not without looping through all keys and testing if `count == 1`.